# Waypoint input fields do not work as SearchBoxes, or return results biased towards the map bounds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am making a bicycle route planner, in which the user can create new input fields for waypoints by clicking a button.

I would like each click of the 'Add waypoint' button to create a single new waypoint input field (up to a maximum of 8), and for each of these created input fields to be SearchBox, returning results biased towards the bounds of the map, and to be included as waypoints when the 'Show route' button is clicked.

At the moment the code will create new input fields for the waypoints, which are included when the route is created, but these newly created input fields are not working as a SearchBox with the results biased towards the map bounds.

Github hosted version: https://gregkaighin.github.io/bicycle-route-planner/
(minimal version as presented in this question)

Github hosted version :https://8000-silver-carp-d746l0fo.ws-eu03.gitpod.io/routes.html (Full version of the project)

```
    const bedfordshire = {
    lat: 52.02973,
    lng: -0.45303
};

const mapOtions = {
    center: bedfordshire,
    zoom: 10,
};

const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOtions);
const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
});
const waypoints = document.getElementsByName("waypoints[]");
for (var i = 0; i < waypoints.length; i++);

function calcRoute() {
    var waypts = [];
    var waypointElmts = document.getElementsByName('waypoints[]');
    for (var i = 0; i < waypointElmts.length; i++) {
        if (waypointElmts[i].value.length > 0) {
            waypts.push({
                location: waypointElmts[i].value,
            });
        }
    }
    var request = {
        origin: document.getElementById('from').value,
        destination: document.getElementById('to').value,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: false,
    }
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);           
        }  
    });
}

// Create searchBox objects for from and to
var input1 = document.getElementById('from');
var searchBox1 = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input1);
map.addListener('bounds_changed', () => {
    searchBox1.setBounds(map.getBounds());
});

var input2 = document.getElementById('to');
var searchBox2 = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input2);
map.addListener('bounds_changed', () => {
    searchBox2.setBounds(map.getBounds());
});

// Functions to create and delete new waypoint search boxes
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Set the maximum number of waypoint inputs
    var max_fields = 9;
    var wrapper = $(".waypoint-input-fields");
    var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            //Add a new input box
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" id="waypoint-inputs" class="form-control" 
name="waypoints[]"/><a href="#" class="delete"> <i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></div>');
        } else {
            alert('Maximum number of waypoints allowed is 8')
        }
    });
    // Delete input box
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bicycle Route Planner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <label for="from" class="control-label direction-input"></label>
    <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Start" class="form-control">
    <!-- Button to add new field for waypoints -->
    <div class="waypoint-input-fields">
        <button class="add_form_field">Add a waypoint</button>
        <label for="to" class=" control-label direction-input form-inline"></label>
        <input type="text" id="to" placeholder="End" class="form-control">
        <button onclick="calcRoute();">Show Route</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
    <div id="route-summary">
    </div>
    <div id="directions-panel">
    </div>
    <!-- Google maps API -->
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=AIzaSyCZA8vB1HcWG1pqWyUyBcyuRI2VDi_fU9U&callback&libraries=places">
    </script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js">
    </script>
    <!-- Routes -->
    <script src="assets/js/map.js"></script>

</body>

</html>

    #map {
    width: 85vw;
    height: 48vh;
    margin: auto;
    
}

#directions-panel {
  margin: auto;
  min-width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: It would be best to create a function that creates the Input fields. This would then apply the Google Maps SearchBox and listeners. This way you can add one or more as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  const bedfordshire = {
    lat: 52.02973,
    lng: -0.45303
  };

  const mapOtions = {
    center: bedfordshire,
    zoom: 10,
  };

  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOtions);
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({});

  function calcRoute() {
    var waypts = [];
    $(".waypoint").each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(el).val().length > 0) {
        waypts.push({
          location: $(el).val(),
        });
      }
    });
    var request = {
      origin: $('#from').val(),
      destination: $('#to').val(),
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: false,
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      }
    });
  }

  function createSearchBox(field, target) {
    if (field == undefined) {
      var holder = $("<div>").appendTo(target);
      field = $("<input>", {
        type: "text",
        class: "form-control search-box waypoint",
        id: "waypoint-" + ($(".waypoint").length + 1),
        placeholder: "Waypoint"
      });
      holder.append(field);
      holder.append("<a href='#' class='delete'> <i class='fas fa-times'></i></a>");
    } else {
      field = $(field);
    }
    var searchbox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(field.get(0));
    map.addListener("bounds_change", function() {
      searchbox.setBounds(maps.getBounds());
    });
  }

  createSearchBox("#from");
  createSearchBox("#to");

  // Set the maximum number of waypoint inputs
  var max_fields = 8;
  var wrapper = $(".waypoint-input-fields");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

  add_button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(".waypoint").length < max_fields) {
      createSearchBox(undefined, wrapper);
    } else {
      alert('Maximum number of waypoints allowed is 8')
    }
  });

  // Delete input box
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
  
  $("#show-route").click(calcRoute);
});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 85vw;
  height: 48vh;
  margin: auto;
}

#directions-panel {
  margin: auto;
  min-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wESLQ85D6gbsF459vf1CiZ2+rr+CsxRY0RpiF1tLlQpDnAgg6rwdsUF1+Ics2bni" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=AIzaSyCZA8vB1HcWG1pqWyUyBcyuRI2VDi_fU9U&callback&libraries=places">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js">
</script>

<div class="start-input-fields">
  <label for="from" class="control-label direction-input"></label>
  <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Start" class="form-control search-box">
  <button class="add_form_field">Add a waypoint</button>
</div>
<div class="waypoint-input-fields"></div>
<div class="end-input-fields">
  <label for="to" class="control-label direction-input form-inline"></label>
  <input type="text" id="to" placeholder="End" class="form-control search-box">
</div>
<button id="show-route">Show Route</button>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="route-summary"></div>
<div id="directions-panel"></div>
```

Here you can see how you can assign or add the Google Search Box to each field. You can see that if the field exists, you can just assign it. If it doe snot, you can add it to a specific target. This is dynamically added and uses the `length` attribute to determine how many of the fields have been added.

Comment: In my initial post I didn't explain what I wanted clearly enough, and I may have misused the word 'dynamically'.

I would like each click of the 'Add waypoint' button to create a single input field, up to a maximum of 8 input fields for the waypoints.

Each of these newly created input fields should be a SearchBox, which returns results biased towards the bounds of the map.

The code you suggested creates more than one input on subsequent clicks, and the ones that do work as a SearchBox, don't return results biased towards the bounds of the map.

Comment: @GregKaighin I updated my answer. Your original code did not indicate a way to set the biased to a specific boundary. I simply used the same code you provided to create the From and To fields to also create the Waypoints.